# ImageView doesn't fit the Image

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-linearlayout

I have this Layout , when I tried to put Image (src="Image")  inside any ImageView , the Image expanded out the ImageView border and cover the whole screen , this is a part of my Layout

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:id="@+id/firstFrame"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/LayoutMargin"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            android:background="@color/frame1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".5"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                >
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

[image: this is the Layout]

I want the Image to be inside ImageView border ,
any solution please ?

Comment: android:scaleType="fitCenter" use this line code every imageview. it is adjust your image in imageview...

Comment: You are not using weights correctly.

Comment: its not working ,,, all the ScalType kinds not working

Comment: where is the problem in weight ,, please tell me

Comment: Wights require the weighted dimension (which can only be one) to be **0dp**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the weight 
if you use Linear Layout as (horizontal) so you should put width = 0dp then you put the weight which u want , 
and vise versa for vertical one

Answer (score 0):

The problem is on first LinearLayout, it must be sumWeight and not layout_weight, or maybe your structure is incomplete.

Comment: bro ,,, the LinearLayout which you see , its just a part from another LinearLayout

Comment: Oh, you should have inserted your whole structure so help could be correct.

Comment: its too too too big